# Display objects (button widgets) aren't shown when they are added to the storyboard display group

Tags: mobile, lua, storyboard, coronasdk

I have a simple scene. There are three button widgets, and a title.

When I include them into the `group`, the objects aren't drawn.  However, when I don't include them, they appear.  But they won't go away when the scene is exited.

I've been reading about the storyboard module, and I'm sure that I'm using it the right way by including them into the group.

Why aren't the display objects drawn when they are included in the group?

I'll include my main.lua, just in case.

main.lua:

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local mydata = require("mydata")

local widget = require( "widget" )

centerX = display.contentCenterX
centerY = display.contentCenterY
_W = display.contentWidth
_H = display.contentHeight

display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

local bkg = display.newImage( "stripes.png", centerX, centerY )

local disclaimer = display.newText("DISCLAIMER", 300-75, centerY-175, 320, 0, "Helvetica", 30 )

local message = display.newText("The creators take no responsibility for\nany damage done by this app, etc.\n", 300-110, centerY-120, 320, 0, "Helvetica", 16)


local howtoTitle = display.newText("HOW TO PLAY", 300-85, centerY-50,320, 0, "Helvetica", 30)
local howto = display.newText("1. Select Time Frame\n      2.Select Sides\n       3.Have Fun", 300-60, centerY, 320, 0, "Helvetica", 16)

mydata.time = 0
mydata.sides = 0
mydata.hits = 0

-- Function to handle button events
local function handleButtonEvent( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    if "ended" == phase then
        event.target:removeSelf()
        disclaimer:removeSelf()
        message:removeSelf()
        howto:removeSelf()
        howtoTitle:removeSelf()
        storyboard.loadScene("time_select")
    end
end

local playButton = widget.newButton {
    left = 100,
    top = 350,
    width = 105,
    height = 39,
    defaultFile = "start.png",
    overFile = "start_pressed.png",
    label = "",
    onEvent = handleButtonEvent,
}
```

time_select.lua:

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local widget = require("widget")

local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local mydata = require("mydata")

local function fifteenSecondButtonEvent( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    if "ended" == phase then
        mydata.time = 15
        storyboard.gotoScene("play")
    end
end

local function thirtySecondButtonEvent( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    if "ended" == phase then
        mydata.time = 30
        storyboard.gotoScene("play")
    end
end

local function sixtySecondButtonEvent( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    if "ended" == phase then
        mydata.time = 60
        storyboard.gotoScene("play")
    end
end



function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    local timeText = display.newText("TIME", 160, 70, "Helvetica", 30)
    group:insert( timeText )

    local fifteenButton = widget.newButton {
        time = 15,
        left = 75,
        top = 150,
        width = 164,
        height = 42,
        defaultFile = "fifteen_button.png",
        overFile = "fifteen_button_pressed.png",
        label = "",
        onRelease = fifteenSecondButtonEvent
    }
    group:insert(fifteenButton)

    local thirtyButton = widget.newButton {
        time = 30,
        left = 75,
        top = 250,
        width = 164,
        height = 42,
        defaultFile = "thirty_button.png",
        overFile = "thirty_button_pressed.png",
        label = "",
        onRelease = thirtySecondButtonEvent
    }
    group:insert(thirtyButton)

    local sixtyButton = widget.newButton {
        time = 60,
        left = 75,
        top = 350,
        width = 164,
        height = 42,
        defaultFile = "sixty_button.png",
        overFile = "sixty_button_pressed.png",
        label = "",
        onRelease = sixtySecondButtonEvent
    }
    group:insert(sixtyButton)
    print( "Number of children in Display Group: " .. group.numChildren )
end

function scene:willEnterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    fifteenButton:removeEventListener( 'onRelease', fifteenSecondButtonEvent ) -- line 92
    thirtyButton:removeEventListener( 'onRelease', thirtySecondButtonEvent )
    sixtyButton:removeEventListener( 'onRelease', sixtySecondButtonEvent )

    timeText:removeSelf()
    timeText = nil
    if fifteenButton then
        fifteenButton:removeSelf()
        fifteenButton = nil
    end

    if thirtyButton then
        thirtyButton:removeSelf()
        thirtyButton = nil
    end

    if sixtyButton then
        sixtyButton:removeSelf()
        sixtyButton = nil
    end

    display.remove(group)
    storyboard.removeScene( "time_select" )

end

function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("willEnterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found an example storyboard that worked on my build (2013.2100), and I played around with it to find my problem.  It was the fact that I was drawing display objects in the main.lua file.  It seems to be convention that the main.lua's only purpose is to direct you to the first scene.  I broke up the previous two files into three separate files, and it all works the way that it's suppose to.

I believe the reason is also a part of @Schollii's answer:

> Display objects that are not placed into a specific group become part of the stage

The `background` was part of the stage, so when it switched to the next scene, it was covered by the display objects on the stage.

@user3439409 I've heard that you must put the listener function inside of the createScene, like how I have it in the code below.  As for the addEventListener, removeEventListener, etc. You shouldn't need to do addEventListener because `widget` does that for you.  However, I heard that you should remove the event listener because it lingers in memory.  You can check for memory leaks by adding a print statement about your memory. For that you can use `storyboard.printMemUsage()`

main.lua (now is just 3 lines):

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

local storyboard = require("storyboard")

storyboard.gotoScene( "start", "fade", 500 )
```

start.lua (what my main.lua had before):

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard")
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

mydata = require("mydata")
widget = require( "widget" )

centerX = display.contentCenterX
centerY = display.contentCenterY
_W = display.contentWidth
_H = display.contentHeight

mydata.time = 0
mydata.sides = 0
mydata.hits = 0

function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    local background = display.newImage( "stripes.png", centerX, centerY )
    background.anchorX, background.anchorY = 0.0,0.0
    background.x, background.y = 0, 0
    group:insert( background )

    local disclaimer = display.newText("DISCLAIMER", 300-75, centerY-175, 320, 0, "Helvetica", 30 )
    group:insert( disclaimer )
    local message = display.newText("The creators take no responsibility for\nany damage done by this app, etc.\n", 300-110, centerY-120, 320, 0, "Helvetica", 16)
    group:insert( message )
    local howtoTitle = display.newText("HOW TO PLAY", 300-85, centerY-50,320, 0, "Helvetica", 30)
    group:insert( howtoTitle )
    local howto = display.newText("1. Select Time Frame\n      2.Select Sides\n       3.Have Fun", 300-60, centerY, 320, 0, "Helvetica", 16)
    group:insert( howto )

    local playButton = nil
    local function handleButtonEvent( event )
        if "ended" == event.phase then
            storyboard.gotoScene("time_select", "fade", 500)
        end
        return true
    end
    playButton = widget.newButton {
        left = 100,
        top = 350,
        width = 105,
        height = 39,
        defaultFile = "start.png",
        overFile = "start_pressed.png",
        label = "",
        onEvent = handleButtonEvent,
    }
    playButton.isActive = true
    group:insert(playButton)
end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

-- Function to handle button events


scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
```

time_select.lua (I put the listener functions inside of the createScene):

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")

local scene = storyboard.newScene()

 local widget = require "widget"

function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    --local background = display.newImage("stripes.png", centerX, centerY)
    --group:insert(backgroundz)

    local background = display.newImage( "stripes.png", centerX, centerY )
    background.anchorX, background.anchorY = 0.0,0.0
    background.x, background.y = 0, 0
    group:insert( background )

    local timeText = display.newText("TIME", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 30)
    timeText.x = _W/2
    timeText.y = _H/2 - 150
    timeText:setFillColor( 255, 255, 255 )
    group:insert(timeText)

    local fifteenButton = nil
    local function fifteenSecondButtonEvent( event )
        if "ended" == event.phase then
            mydata.time = 15
            storyboard.gotoScene("sides_selection")
        end
        return true
    end
    fifteenButton = widget.newButton {
        left = 75,
        top = 150,
        width = 164,
        height = 42,
        defaultFile = "fifteen_button.png",
        overFile = "fifteen_button_pressed.png",
        label = "",
        onRelease = fifteenSecondButtonEvent
    }
    fifteenButton.isActive = true
    group:insert(fifteenButton)

    local thirtyButton = nil
    local function thirtySecondButtonEvent( event )
        local phase = event.phase
        if "ended" == phase then
            mydata.time = 30
            storyboard.gotoScene("play")
        end
    end
    thirtyButton = widget.newButton {
        left = 75,
        top = 250,
        width = 164,
        height = 42,
        defaultFile = "thirty_button.png",
        overFile = "thirty_button_pressed.png",
        label = "",
        onRelease = thirtySecondButtonEvent
    }
    thirtyButton.active = true
    group:insert(thirtyButton)

    local sixtySecondButtonEvent = nil
    local function sixtySecondButtonEvent( event )
        local phase = event.phase
        if "ended" == phase then
            mydata.time = 60
            storyboard.gotoScene("play")
        end
    end
    sixtyButton = widget.newButton {
        left = 75,
        top = 350,
        width = 164,
        height = 42,
        defaultFile = "sixty_button.png",
        overFile = "sixty_button_pressed.png",
        label = "",
        onRelease = sixtySecondButtonEvent
    }
    group:insert(sixtyButton)
end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene
```

Comment: +1 for second part of answer. Don't need listener inside, and don't need first scene to be in separate file, and only Runtime listeners need explicit removal. so I have extended my answer to discuss these points, as they could mislead other novice users of Corona.

Comment: Thank you for your wisdom and guidance.  Picking up Corona + Lua has been rough.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `storyboard.loadScene("time_select")`. This loads the scene but does not show it, so you don't see the objects that you add to its view group. When you don't add the objects to the view group, they do show up, because by default objects get put in the default "root level" group, called the *stage*. From *Drawing Model* section of [Group Programming Guide](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/group.html):

> Display objects that are not placed into a specific group become part of the stage

Use instead `storyboard.gotoScene("time_select")` so that your app transitions to the other scene (unless you meant for the `time_select` to be an overlay, then use `storyboard.showOverlay`).

Update: looks like there were two issues, as demonstrated by your own answer. I copied your fixed code to my simulator and executed it and sure enough, with `loadScene()` I couldn't see anything; I had to use `gotoScene()`.

However, there are couple things that are incorrect in your answer:

1. the main.lua can create first scene: `scene = storbyboard.newScene("scene1")` then `storyboard.gotoScene("uniqueName")` and all the scene1 event handlers (createScene etc) can be in main.lua.
2. You can put the listener functions anywhere you want.
3. Listeners registered on objects are automatically unregistered when object calls removeSelf. Runtime is not a display object so for Runtime listeners like "enterFrame", you must explicitely removeEventHandler when exiting a scene.
4. You don't need to `removeSelf` objects in `destroyScene`, because this automatically done for you when `scene.view` is removed (automatic after `destroyScene` called).
5. You should not be calling `removeScene('time_select')` in `time_select.exitScene`, that makes no sense! the removeScene in exit will cause destroyScene to be called from exitScene! If you know you no longer need `time_select` scene, you would remove it from (for example) the main scene's `enterScene`. This will call time_select's destroyScene, and remove the scene.view group. The latter will remove every object in the group (which will unregister listeners of those objects), recursively.

These two points are demonstrated below: I moved your scene1.lua into main.lua and fixed main.lua accordingly; and I moved the handleButtonEvent out of the createScene.

main.lua:

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local widget = require "widget"

local scene = storyboard.newScene("scene1")

local mydata = {} -- require("mydata")
local widget = require( "widget" )

local centerX = display.contentCenterX
local centerY = display.contentCenterY
local _W = display.contentWidth
local _H = display.contentHeight

mydata.time = 0
mydata.sides = 0
mydata.hits = 0

local function handleButtonEvent( event )
    if "ended" == event.phase then
        storyboard.gotoScene("time_select", "fade", 500)
    end
    return true
end

function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    local background = display.newImage( "stripes.png", centerX, centerY )
    background.anchorX, background.anchorY = 0.0,0.0
    background.x, background.y = 0, 0
    group:insert( background )

    local disclaimer = display.newText("DISCLAIMER", 300-75, centerY-175, 320, 0, "Helvetica", 30 )
    group:insert( disclaimer )
    local message = display.newText("The creators take no responsibility for\nany damage done by this app, etc.\n", 300-110, centerY-120, 320, 0, "Helvetica", 16)
    group:insert( message )
    local howtoTitle = display.newText("HOW TO PLAY", 300-85, centerY-50,320, 0, "Helvetica", 30)
    group:insert( howtoTitle )
    local howto = display.newText("1. Select Time Frame\n      2.Select Sides\n       3.Have Fun", 300-60, centerY, 320, 0, "Helvetica", 16)
    group:insert( howto )

    local playButton = widget.newButton {
        left = 100,
        top = 350,
        width = 105,
        height = 39,
        label = "Play",
        onEvent = handleButtonEvent,
    }
    playButton.isActive = true
    group:insert(playButton)
end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

-- load first scene
storyboard.gotoScene( "scene1", "fade", 400 )
```

The time_select.lua`:

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local widget = require("widget")

local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local mydata = {} -- require("mydata")

local function fifteenSecondButtonEvent( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    if "ended" == phase then
        mydata.time = 15
        storyboard.gotoScene("play")
    end
end

local function thirtySecondButtonEvent( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    if "ended" == phase then
        mydata.time = 30
        storyboard.gotoScene("play")
    end
end

local function sixtySecondButtonEvent( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    if "ended" == phase then
        mydata.time = 60
        storyboard.gotoScene("play")
    end
end

function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    local timeText = display.newText("TIME", 160, 70, "Helvetica", 30)
    group:insert( timeText )

    local fifteenButton = widget.newButton {
        time = 15,
        left = 75,
        top = 150,
        width = 164,
        height = 42,
        label = "15 Button",
        onRelease = fifteenSecondButtonEvent
    }
    group:insert(fifteenButton)

    local thirtyButton = widget.newButton {
        time = 30,
        left = 75,
        top = 250,
        width = 164,
        height = 42,
        label = "30 Button",
        onRelease = thirtySecondButtonEvent
    }
    group:insert(thirtyButton)

    local sixtyButton = widget.newButton {
        time = 60,
        left = 75,
        top = 350,
        width = 164,
        height = 42,
        label = "45 Button",
        onRelease = sixtySecondButtonEvent
    }
    group:insert(sixtyButton)
    print( "Number of children in Display Group: " .. group.numChildren )
end

function scene:willEnterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

local demoNonObjListenerCount
local function enterFrame(event)
    demoNonObjListenerCount = demoNonObjListenerCount + 1 
end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', enterFrame)
end

function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    Runtime:removeEventListener('enterFrame', enterFrame)    
end

function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    -- self.view will be removed upon return, which will 
    -- remove display objects contained, recursively, so 
    -- here not much else to do
end

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("willEnterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene
```

The contents of `time_select.lua` could even be put in `main.lua` if you replaced every occurence of "scene" by, say, "timeSelect" and used `timeSelect = storyboard.newScene("time_select")`. However, modularity is better, so better leave `time_select` scenario in its own file, but the `scene1` does not have to be in separate file from `main.lu`a.

Comment: Your explanation makes a lot of sense. I switched out `loadScene` for `gotoScene` in main.lua, however it still refuses to show up.  I tried other storyboard examples I found, and they all don't work, I feel that it could be my build version (2013.2100)

Comment: @EjayTumacder If none of the examples work with your installation of 2100 then all bets are off, however I do believe that once you do find a version of Corona that works for out-of-the-box examples, the you will have to change your code as per above. Note that 2100 is stable release it the one I use, I would try uninstall and re-install. Also what do you mean by "don't work"?

Comment: Sorry, I should elaborate more on "don't work".  They all seem to give me blank screens. I used this https://github.com/RevMob/corona-sample-with-storyboard and the code attached to this http://www.develephant.net/a-simple-storyboard-framework-for-corona-sdk-part-1/ just to name a few.  They all seem to not work

Comment: With the Corona simulator open, you see on the right side it says "Docs Samples Forum Learn"? Select one of the samples from the Getting Started group. Do they samples run?

Comment: I found the solution, the reason seems to be part of the answer that you posted.  I don't think anything is wrong with my build at all. I guess I was just frustrated :)

Comment: @EjayTumacder yes, I tested your code from your question and can run it with only minor mods, which I explain in my update. The issue was totally the loadScene vs gotoScene.

Comment: Those minor mods made a difference.  I used an image for a backgorund 'stripes.png'.  A picture that is in the "CollisionFilter" folder in the Sample Projects if you want to test it.  When the image was used, it over shadowed the display objects.  It did have to do with loadScene or gotoScene, but was only part of the solution.  The background image prevented gotoScene() from working.  I mean no disrespect.

Comment: @EjayTumacder No worries. I tried your code and replaced the gotoScene time_select with loadScene and indeed doesn't work. But you are right, display objects that are not added to a scene are added to the root group, which could hide some scenes depending on order of non scene objects in group hierarchy. +1 for having found the other half of the puzzle! I edited my answer to address a couple things you say in your answer which are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using story board then you need to call storyboard.removeScene() method for removing all the object from display group.
Here is the reference. 
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/removeScene.html
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/